# Access SQL count() query

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

This task should be done in Access with 1 query. 
There are 3 tables:

- `address {id, address, city, postalcode, country, supplierid}`
- `supplier {supplierID, supplierName, nameid}`
- `contactname {nameid, firstname, lastname, phone}`

I need to create query, that results with the following table:

```
{country, supplierNumber, supplierName, firstname, lastname, phone}
```

Where `supplierNumber` is number of companies in specific country.

For countries with only 1 company `country, supplierName, firstname, lastname, phone` fields must be filled; with 2 or more companies `country, supplierNumber` fields must be filled.

So I had straightforward idea to use:

```
SELECT COUNT() ... 
FROM ... INNER JOIN ... ON ...
HAVING COUNT() ...
GROUP BY ...
UNION
...
```

But I got stucked with a lot of problems. `GROUP BY` requires all fields that `SELECT` takes because of `COUNT()`;  `UNION` requires equal number of fields in tables, so maybe the second table should be complemented with `NULL` fields or something. So I have no idea, which way this task should be implemented. Please, help me.

Comment: So, what is your attempt with this ?

Comment: I wrote I tried to create query with structure I described above, but all in vain.

Comment: Why downvote? Firstly, It's no use publishing my attempt, because it's absolutely non-working, secondly, I precisely described the structure and the mistakes I had during my attempt. Lastly, I unsuccessfully searched the web thouroughly for similar examples and doesn't even know the principle this task should be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `address.supplierid` is always filled with a valid `supplierid` and `supplier.nameid` is always filled with a valid `nameid`, you can achieve the desired result using a `UNION` query like the following. The first part selects the country and supplier/contact for countries with only one supplier, the second part selects all contries with more that one supplier (countries with more than one address):

```
SELECT a.country, 1 AS supplierNumber, s.supplierName, c.firstname, c.lastname, c.phone
FROM (address AS a INNER JOIN supplier AS s ON a.supplierid = s.supplierid) 
  INNER JOIN contactname AS c ON s.nameid = c.nameid
WHERE ((a.country) In (SELECT country FROM address GROUP BY country HAVING Count(*)=1))
UNION
SELECT a.country, Count(*), Null, Null, Null, Null
FROM address AS a GROUP BY country HAVING Count(*)>1
```

Comment: WolfgangK, works perfectly, just amazing... I am so much grateful to you! So many implicit features in sql to use!

Answer (score 0):

Consider joining your unit level tables with aggregate level query:

```
SELECT a.country, agg.supplierNumber, s.supplierName, c.firstname, c.lastname, c.phone
FROM ((supplier s
INNER JOIN contact c ON c.nameid = s.nameid)
INNER JOIN address a ON s.supplierid = a.supplierid)
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT sub_a.country, COUNT(*) AS supplierNumber
    FROM address sub_a
    INNER JOIN supplier sub_s ON sub_a.supplierid = sub_s.supplier_id
    GROUP BY sub_a.country) AS agg
ON agg.country = a.country
```

Comment: Wow, very smart idea and it seems to work well, but there are all fields filled up in 
the resulting table for each country!